# Should it be "has" or "have" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Your examples of faith, love, partnership and trust **has** given us...

or

> Your examples of faith, love, partnership and trust **have** given us...

Comment: The number of the verb is governed by the number of the subject. Identify the subject and you have your answer.

Comment: Not to give away the game, but "Your example of W, X, Y, and Z" would lead to one form of the verb and "Your examples of W, X, Y, and Z" would lead to the other.

Answer (score 1):

**Examples** is the subject. The "of" prepositional phrase modifies the subject, but doesn't change the plurality of the subject. The predicate would have to agree with the plural subject, so **have** is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Even if one thought the **of** prepositional phrases were the subject, which they're not, the subject would be plural because the final conjunction was **and**. **Examples** is the subject. The "of" prepositional phrase modifies the subject, but doesn't change the plurality of the subject. The predicate would have to agree with the plural subject, so **have** is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, the examples listed are the subject. The subject is plural. Therefore, the correct word would be `have`.

[Examples here.](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/using-have-and-has/)

Answer (score -1):

Has usually is used w/the 3rd person singular he/she/it has. Has is singular and have is meant for plural forms, the 2nd person, and I.

ex. I have, you have, we have, they have.

In your sentence, love, partnership and trust are listed in a series, so your referring to more than one thing. "Have given us" is the correct form. If you were using only love or any one of the others listed in the series alone, then you'd use has.